# XCode Debugger viewing variables

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I'm attempting to step through some code where I have a variable:
view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
Looking at the variable in XCode I see:
[image: XCode Screenshot of variables]

Since this is an instance of a UIView there are structures that I'm unfamiliar with (e.g subViewCache).  Is there some document explaining what these other structures are for?  Where can I drill down to to find the annotation object (view.annotation) that I want to view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, anything start with underscore means it is private variable, which (normally) won't be documented and subject to change. The best you can do is guess the meaning from the name and hope there is something called `_annotation`.

However, you can use lldb command `po view.annotation` to ask debugger to print that property for you

Comment: the console window, where you see logs. when paused, it will prompt `lldb)`

Comment: It just gives: <BasicMapAnnotation: 0x78ea5e80>  and if I try po view.annotation.coordinate.latitude I get 'property 'coordinate' not found on object of type 'id''

Comment: you need to learn some basic lldb usage. in this case, you want `p (CLLocationCoordinate2D)[(id)[view annotation] coordinate]`

Comment: where is a good tutorial that shows its use in the XCode context?

Comment: this is from apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/gdb_to_lldb_transition_guide/document/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012917-CH1-SW1

Answer (score -1):

Or you could create a temporary variable where you are trying to debug:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D tempCoord = annotation.coordinate;
```

You should be able to see the long and lat from tempCoord if you hover over it while debugging.